# How does differential mode noise and common mode noise occur

Tags: voltage, current, noise, differential, common-mode

I was reading [this](https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/emc/s-emc/01-s-emc/6899) article on common mode and differential mode noise.

But it is not mentioned anywhere on how the differential mode noise and common mode noise occurs.

From the diagram, I kind of understand like, due to the stray capacitance and parasitics, the common mode noise occurs. But what is the reason for the differential mode noise? How does it occur?

It would be really helpful for me if one could draw up the noise waveform on both the (+ve and return path) for the differential mode noise.

Comment: Are you in fact asking how noise (or interference) occurs?

Comment: Like, what causes these noises? Differential mode noises

Comment: How is a (differential) signal generated? It might be a signal from a sensor which has been amplified. The sensor and the amplifier both add noise to the signal that you want to measure. That noise will be differential noise as it is added to the differential signal.

Comment: So, will the differential noise waveform be same on both the lines of the differential signal or will it be opposite?

Comment: *will the differential noise waveform be same on both the lines of the differential signal or will it be opposite?* You need to **think** and realize that signal and noise are treated in the same way. If we were talking about a signal instead of noise, would the polarity of a differential signal be opposite or not? Now consider that the same applies to noise as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

There you go, imagine the sources as noise injection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYqk5y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>